# Bootstrap 2nd level sub-menus not closing on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On click on "D boards" dropdown the submenus appears, but on click it is not closing. Similarly on click of "T Dashboard" also the submenus not closing. Below is what I implemented so far. Please help me know where I went wrong.

I imported boostrap3.js and jquery-1.11.3.min.js

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1jsm5sv0/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
                        window.onunload = function () { null };

                        $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {

                            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);

                        }, function () {

                            $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);

                        });

                        $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function (event) {

                            event.preventDefault();

                            event.stopPropagation();

                            $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');

                            $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');

                        });

                    });

                    function preventBack() { window.history.forward(); }


                </script>
                <script>
                    $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function (e) {
                        if ($(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
                            $(this).collapse('hide');
                        }
                    });
                </script>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin:5px 0px 0px 20px;font-size:medium;">
                                <li runat="server" id="Home"><a href="Index.aspx" class="linkColor">A & B</a></li>
                                <li runat="server" id="account"><a href="AccountTeam.aspx" class="linkColor">AB Team</a></li>
                                <li runat="server" id="adminPage"><a href="AdminPage.aspx" class="linkColor">Admin</a></li>
                                <li runat="server" id="Dashboards">
                                    <a id="dLabel" role="link" data-toggle="dropdown" class="" data-target="navbar-collapse" href="" class="linkColor">
                                        D boards<span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                        <li><a href="P.aspx" class="linkColor">C Dashboard</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a tabindex="-1" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">T Dashboard</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="F.aspx" class="linkColor">F</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="M.aspx" class="linkColor">B</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="L.aspx" class="linkColor">L</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li runat="server" id="Learning">
                                    <a role="link" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="" class="linkColor">
                                        Learning Stop<span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                                        <li><a href="B.aspx" class="linkColor">B</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="T.aspx" class="linkColor">T</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="P.aspx" class="linkColor">P</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li runat="server"><a href="Login.aspx" id="logOff" runat="server" class="linkColor">Log Off</a></li>
                                <li runat="server"><a href="Login.aspx" id="signIn" runat="server" class="linkColor">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li runat="server"><a href="UserRegistration.aspx" id="signUp" runat="server" class="linkColor">Sign Up</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you provide an example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1jsm5sv0/1/

Comment: See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/1jsm5sv0/2/). I just removed `.collapse` from `div.navbar-collapse` to make it visible. Is this not what you are expecting?

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Thanks for the minor catch.